# Using a database in .amat format in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, keras

I want to import a series of data bases from [here](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/%7Elisa/twiki/bin/view.cgi/Public/DeepVsShallowComparisonICML2007#Downloadable_datasets). They are all in .amat format, which I completely don't understand. I need to train a small classifier in keras with these datasets. Any idea on how I can import and read them in python ?

Comment: If what you're trying to load is MNIST standard data, go straight for keras: https://keras.io/datasets/#mnist-database-of-handwritten-digits

Comment: I suspect "amat" is not really a meaningful extension.... have you tried to open the files on notepad to check whether they're just a plain text file or a CSV?

Comment: I ended up reading the file as a standard text file.

Comment: @Qubix did you need to do any processing to convert them into numpy arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy to import and read the files.

For instance:

```
import numpy a np

data = np.loadtxt('train.amat')
```

If you have a image files stored in the amat format, then

```
# get train image datas
x_train = data[:, :-1] / 1.0

# get test image labels
y_train = data[:, -1:]
```

Please don't confuse with the indexes: data[:, :-1]. The second -1 referes to the last index is label, therefore I omitted.

Hope this helps.